# Invalid mex file, morphmex.mexw32 the specified modules could not be found

Tags: c#, matlab, mex, matlab-deployment

I wrote a program in Matlab for image processing and created .dll of that program using matlab builder ne. my matlab version is 2010a. I wrote a program in c# to use the matlab function. It worked on my computer where matlab was installed. but when I installed MCR on a computer without matlab and wanted to run the program, a c# exception thrown. 
It said that:

MWMCR::EvaluateFunction error
Invalid MEX-file ...\toolbox\images\images\private\morphmex.mexw32': The specified module could not be found.
Error in =>MYMATFUNC.m at 6.

... Matlab M-code Stack Trace ...
    at
file ...\toolbox\images\images\private\morphop.m,name ....

Can anyone help to solve the problem?

Comment: Is it a 32/64 bit problem perhaps?

Comment: No I tried it on the same architecture without matlab, but the problem exists.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem with Matlab 2010a and Matlab Builder NE 3.1, and no workaround fixed it. Yesterday, I upgraded to Matlab 2010bSp1 / Builder NE 3.2 and now it works perfectly.

Cheers
uwe

Comment: Thanks for reply. I may try that!